# How to change the filename's color on rename popup in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2019.03, when "rename" a PHP file, the text color of file name in the popup is white while the background color is also white, and so it's invisible.

How to change the text color of file name?

BTW, I'm using Material UI plugin, and this is using Atom One Light.

[image]

Comment: You can try using different GUI Theme, e.g. bundled Darcula (`Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Theme`) or any custom theme you want (can be installed as an ordinary plugin -- `Settings/Preferences | Plugins` and search for "theme").

Comment: Hi, I'm using material theme, and this is the theme I had chosen, because everything else looks good. I just want to know how to change this specific color.

Comment: That color should already be normal/readable one. Material Theme is known to create some issues here and there that are not present otherwise (due to the way how it does theming, sometimes making quite big changes in IDE). Therefore please contact Material Theme plugin author about this issue because it has to be some bug/issue with the plugin.